# Window 7 & Windows Server 2008 R2: significant increase in run time

Tags: delphi, windows-7, delphi-7, windows-server-2008-r2

We are developing a console software, with Delphi 7.

To simplify, this software is using an embedded TCP server to answer to external requests from a CGI. These answers contain generated HTML pages with Teechart graphs, and data extracted from a database, using DbExpress.

On Windows 7 and Windows 2008 R2 servers, we noticed significant increase of the run time of our software – 2 or 3 times the original process time on Windows XP or Windows Server 2003 – in a standard context of execution: software launched as a Service with the system user account.

But when our software is launched as a simple user, from command prompt, or directly from the IDE (debug mode), the problem simply disappear.

**My first question is : has anyone already noticed this problem?**

Using ProcessExplorer, we also noticed that when the software is launched as a service, there is no GDI Handle created, nor is a User Handle. But when the software is launched with a user account, some of these handles are created. With Windows XP  and Windows Server 2003, either the software is launched as a service or with a simple user account, these handles are always created.

**Can this observation be linked with our problem?**

**If you already noticed these behaviour, how did you fix the problem?**

Comment: Add some trace logging to the process and work out where it is spending its time. Could be a million reasons for this.

Comment: Obviously the big change for services from XP/2003 to Vista/7/2008/2008R2 is session 0 isolation. That is likely to be at the root of this. How it affects your process is hard to us to guess at.

Comment: Hello

Thank you for your comments.
I was thinking about detailed trace logs, but I was afraid that they would not be significant because they are not performed on identical computers.
However, the comparison of ratios of time should provides clues, I'll try.

Regarding the "Session 0 Isolation" is indeed an interesting idea, I'll dig. But from what I see, at first reading,
I should have problems with Server 2008 too, or I only have problems with Server 2008 R2 (not tested on Vista yet )

Comment: Session 0 isolation is Vista/7/8/server 2008/server 2008 r2, i.e. win version >= 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we found the source of our problems. So for those that are looking for a solution, here's what we’ve done:

Delays are due to the use of Win32 API functions using locals. Using a Locale Identifier functions are now being deprecated in favor of using the Locale Name functions (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319091%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Our developments use significantly “CompareString” (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317759%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), including the use of the indexOf method of the TStringList .The execution of this method (CompareStringA of kernell32) is slowed while running in the user context System (in Session 0).

To get around this problem, we overloaded TStringList with CompareStr instead of CompareString. This workaround suits in our context but CompareStr makes comparisons bit to bit and isn't case sensitive unlike CompareString. (Not to mention the fact that this method is about 10 times faster ... http://www.gefvert.org/blog/archives/651)

Another solution would be to switch to a newer version of the IDE, but we all know that this is another story...

Answer (score 2):

Because of the many places where we relied on Windows API CompareString function we could not replace it by non Windows versions.
But, we found that instead of using LOCAL_USER_DEFAULT by using LOCALE_INVARIANT($07) the API works fine.
So, we decided to hack the constant value as defined in Windows and over write it everywhere where it was used for comparison purposes with a conditional compilation like this:

```
{$IFDEF OVERLOAD_LUD}
const
  LOCALE_INVARIANT = $7;
  LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT = LOCALE_INVARIANT;
{$ENDIF}
```

That solved the problem.